# Read the database file in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlite

I am creating two applications like A and B. In A i am creating db file using SQLiteOpenHelper . Is it possible to open that database file in app B ?

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't. the database file create at `/data/data/<package_name>/databases/<name>.db`,other app doesn't has permission to read this file.

consider share data between app with `ContentProvider`

Answer (score 0):

> do one thing go in ddms and pull your database like .db file from sdcard
>   and then again copy that .db file and paste in assets folder of that secound application and try
>   to access that database like this 
>   http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/